# JavaFx ComboBox binding confusion

Tags: java, scala, javafx

I have an I18N implementation that binds JavaFX UI elements through properties, for e.g.:

```
def translateLabel(l: Label, key: String, args: Any*): Unit =
    l.textProperty().bind(createStringBinding(key, args))
```

Having a property binding is easy and works well. However I struggle with ComboBox as it takes an ObservableList (of Strings in my case) and I have no idea how to bind my translator functions to that. I am conflicted about the difference between `ObservableValue`, `ObservableList` and `Property` interfaces as they all sound the same.

It has `itemsProperty()` and `valueProperty()` however the documentation for these is lacking and vague so I am not sure where they can be used.

What I want to do is have a ComboBox where all elements (or at least the selected / visible one) changes the language dynamically (I18N) as if it was bound, just like a property.

EDIT:

Just to make it easier understand, my current implementation is:

```
private def setAggregatorComboBox(a: Any): Unit = {

    val items: ObservableList[String] = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        noneOptionText.getValue,
        "COUNT()",
        "AVG()",
        "SUM()"
    )

    measureAggregatorComboBox.getItems.clear()

    measureAggregatorComboBox.getItems.addAll(items)
}
```

Where `noneOptionText` is a `StringProperty` that's already bound to a `StringBinding` that's translated upon class instantiation in this manner:

```
def translateString(sp: StringProperty, key: String, args: Any*): Unit =
        sp.bind(createStringBinding(key, args))
```

Comment: `items` is not going to work as you want; `noneOptionText.getValue` will be evaluated when `items` is created; the value of the first element will not change when the value of `noneOptionText` changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `itemsProperty()` is the [list of items to show in the combo box popup](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#itemsProperty); it's value is an `ObservableList`.

The `valueProperty()` is the [selected item](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#valueProperty) (or the value input by the user if the combo box is editable).

What I'd recommend is to have the *data* in the combo box be the list of keys, and use custom cells to bind the text in each cell to the translation of those keys. I don't speak scala, but in Java it looks like:

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.getItems().setAll(getAllKeys());

class TranslationCell extends ListCell<String> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        textProperty().unbind();
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText("");
        } else {
            textProperty().bind(createStringBinding(item));
        }
    }
}

comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new TranslationCell());
comboBox.setButtonCell(new TranslationCell());
```

Note now that the `valueProperty()` contains the *key* for the selected value.

If you really want to bind the items to an `ObservableValue<ObservableList<String>>` you can do something like:

```
comboBox.itemsProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(...),
    ...));
```

where the first `...` is a varargs of `String` values, and the second `...` is an observable value, changes in which would prompt the list to be recomputed. (So in your case, I'm guessing you have an `ObservableValue<Locale>` somewhere representing the current locale; you would use that for the second argument.)

In your specific use case (where only the first element of the list is internationalizable), it might be easier simply to use a listener:

```
comboBox.getItems().setAll(
    noneOptionTest.getValue(), 
    "COUNT()",
    "AVG()",
    "SUM");
noneOptionTest.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) ->
    comboBox.getItems().set(0, newVal));
```

though I agree this is slightly less elegant.

For completeness:

> I am conflicted about the difference between `ObservableValue`,
> `ObservableList` and `Property` interfaces as they all sound the same.

`ObservableValue<T>`: represents a single value of type `T` which can be *observed* (meaning that code can be executed when it changes).

`Property<T>`: represents a *writable* `ObservableValue<T>`; the intention is that implementations would have an actual variable representing the value. It defines additional functionality allowing its value to be bound to other `ObservableValue<T>`.

So, for example:

```
DoubleProperty x = new SimpleDoubleProperty(6);
DoubleProperty y = new SimpleDoubleProperty(9);
ObservableValue<Number> product = x.multiply(y);
```

`x` and `y` are both `Property<Number>`; the implementation of `SimpleDoubleProperty` has an actual `double` variable representing this value, and you can do things like `y.set(7);` to change the value.

On the other hand, `product` is not a `Property<Number>`; you can't change its value (because doing so would violate the *binding*: the declared invariant that `product.getValue() == x.getValue() * y.getValue()`); however it is *observable*, so you can bind to it:

```
BooleanProperty answerCorrect = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
answerCorrect.bind(product.isEqualTo(42));
```

etc.

An `ObservableList` is somewhat different: it is a `java.util.List` (a collection of elements), and you can observe it to respond to *operations on the list*. I.e. if you add a listener to an `ObservableList`, the listener can determine if elements were added or removed, etc.

Comment: _the value is slightly more complex if the combo box is editable_ hmm .. what do you mean? It's always (except if the value is bound) the selected item, independent on editability

Comment: @kleopatra If editable, the `value` might not be an "item", in the sense of being an element of `getItems()`; i.e. it might not be something *selected* from the list of items. (We could argue about the semantics of what is meant by "selected item"; is something that's typed in "selected", etc. But...) Edited for clarity.

Comment: still the selectedItem (in terms of the selectionModel) _is_ the value - which may be contained in the items or not :). The invariant:  `assertEquals(box.getValue(), box.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` must hold always and must not depend on editability (there are some bugs violating it ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Is that true? The [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) say "Clearing the selection in the selection model does not null the valueProperty; it remains the same as before". So after clearing the selection model, either `getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != getValue()` or `getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null && getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().size() == 0`, which seems even weirder...

Comment: the doc is broken and illogical ;) post-condition of selectionModel.clear is selectedIndex == -1 (well .... there are bugs violating this also, though not for combo selection), the selectedItem (and with it the value) might still be != null if it is not contained in the items

Comment: @kleopatra Ah, ok, your invariant is true then; it's just that the semantics of `SelectionModel` are illogical (which I should have known...).

Comment: well, hair-splitting a bit: a) the semantics (aka: specification in the doc) of SelectionModel is ill-defined (there are bugs spelling that out.. ) b) it's not per-se illogical to allow an uncontained item to be selectedItem c) the uncontained-selectedItem case is overlooked by both model implementations in core and users <g> Just spent (or still spending) some time trying to clean combo selection up (that's why I'm rather familiar with the dirty details right now), not overly successful though, too much dirt which would require a power showel to move away ..

Comment: Thank you both for your help, that worked perfectly.

Comment: @James_D just to correct, itemsProperty() returns ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>, not ObservableValue<ObservableList<String>>

Comment: @Shobe However, `ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>` is an implementation of `ObservableValue<ObservableList<T>>`, so it's also true that `itemsProperty()` returns an `ObservableValue<ObservableList<T>>`. And what I actually stated was about *binding*: any `Property<S>` can be *bound to* any `ObservableValue<S>`. So `itemsProperty().bind(...)` can accept any `ObservableValue<ObservableList<T>>` (which is what's returned by the `Bindings.createObjectBinding(...)` code I used). (I agree the API is somewhat over-engineered.)

Comment: @James_D makes perfect sense, thank you for the explanation

Comment: @James_D really appreciate your effort, thank you again for a clear explanation!