# JavaFX Cell and setCellFactory confusion

Tags: java, scala, javafx

I am learning the Cell and cell factory API's. I have read many examples and I can't wrap my head around how setCellFactory or setCellValuesFactory actually work.

Here are the examples in Scala (apologies Java users):

#1:

```
val cb = new javafx.util.Callback[ListView[Number], ListCell[Number]] {

    override def call(list: ListView[Number]): ListCell[Number] = {
        new MoneyFormatCell
    }
}
```

#2:

```
class TranslationCell extends ListCell[String] {

    override protected def updateItem(item: String, empty: Boolean) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty)
        textProperty().unbind()

        if (empty || item == null) setText("") ?else textProperty().bind(createStringBinding(item))
    }
}
```

Please ignore the different types and login within the Callback and the TranslationCell class, they aren't relevant in this case.

Now, if I do this, both options work:

```
x.setCellFactory(cb)
y.setCellFactory(lv => new TranslationCell)
```

I don't understand how or why the `y` case works as the `setCellFactory` takes a `Callback[A]` and an instance of `TranslationCell` which extends `ListCell[B]`.

I also don't understand what the `updateItem`method has to do with the function and how I can pass an instance of `TranslationCell` to the `setCellFactory` without any issues.

What's the relation between `updateItem` and `setCellFactory`?

Comment: "I don't understand how or why the y case works as the setCellFactory takes a Callback[A] and a ListCell[B]". It takes a `Callback`. Why do you think it can take a `ListCell`?

Comment: @James_D my bad, I was meant to say an instance of a class that extends ListCell

Comment: An instance of a class that extends `ListCell` is still a `ListCell`. But there's nowhere in your code that you do that. (It wouldn't compile if you did.)

Comment: @James_D how come? This was your implementation for a ComboBox in my older question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128325/javafx-combobox-binding-confusion/65128574?noredirect=1#comment115143528_65128574

Comment: Again, there is nowhere that you (or I) pass anything that is a `ListCell` to the `setCellFactory()` method. That method takes a `Callback`, which is what you are passing it.

Comment: @James_D in that implementation there is a class that extends `ListCell`. An instance of that class is passed into `setCellFactory()` method.

Comment: "An instance of that class is passed into setCellFactory() method.". No it isn't!!! Where????

Comment: @James_D a lambda that returns an instance of that class to be precise*

Comment: @James_D this line to be exact: `comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new TranslationCell());`

Comment: But that's not the same thing. You're passing a function (lambda) that takes `lv` as a parameter and returns a `ListCell`. Which is exactly the signature of the `call()` method in the `Callback` (if `lv` is a `ListView`, which the compiler can infer unambiguously). So you're passing a `Callback`, not a `ListCell`.

Comment: Passing a `ListCell`, i.e. `comboBox.setCellFactory(new TranslationCell())` will not compile, as you can verify.

Comment: @James_D oh that's clever, I would have never thought of that as my compiler says `lv` is unused. Putting that comment of yours in the answer could be useful! Thank you again, I understand now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setCellFactory` method takes a `Callback<ListView<T>,ListCell<T>>`, i.e. a function mapping a `ListView<T>` to a `ListCell<T>`. Nowhere in the code you posted do you pass a `ListCell` to the `setCellFactory` method.

The `ListView` works internally by creating as many cells as it needs to display the visible content. Note that, since the `ListView` is scrollable, this may be many fewer than the number of items contained in the `ListView`. The `ListCell`s are created by calling the `Callback` passed to the `setCellFactory()` method as many times as needed in order to create the number of cells needed. Typically, if the `ListView` is large enough to display, for example, 10 cells, it will call the cell factory's `Callback` at least 10 times (it may create one or two "spare" cells).

In order to actually display the content of the cells, the `ListView` will call each cell's `updateItem()` method, passing in the item to be displayed (or `null`), and a boolean representing whether this cell is "empty". The implementation of the `updateItem()` method should set the text and/or graphic of the cell based on the `item` to be displayed.

At various points of a cell's lifespan, it may be asked to display a different item. For example, as the user scrolls around the `ListView`, instead of creating new cells for the newly-displayed items and discarding the old ones (which would place a considerable strain on the garbage collector at some point), the `ListView` will simply "reuse" the existing cells, asking them to display a different item instead. The actual implementation of this is (deliberately) not defined; all that you know is that the `updateItem()` method will be called any time the cell needs to update its display.

Note that this means your `updateItem()` method needs to handle all possibilities; it may go from empty to non-empty, from non-empty to empty, or from displaying one item to displaying a different item. Thus the `updateItem()` method must set the text and/or graphic in any code path. If you do other things, such as change the style, you should again do so in any possible code path in the `updateItem()` method.

Comment: Thank you again for stringing it together (I'm learning!).

I have edited my mistake, I was meant to say TranslationCell which extends ListCell[B].